# awscli error - Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to create an environment using:

`eb create xxx-env --database`

but I'm getting the following Python error:

> Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

From reading [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244727) it seems that the issue is to do with the cli tool not being able to get the credentials.

I have created a **.aws/config** file and a **./aws/credentials** file but still nothing.

`eb --version` =
`EB CLI 3.14.6 (Python 3.5.2)`

Has anyone come up against this?

EDIT

The full output of the `eb create` command is:

> Enter an RDS DB username (default is "ebroot"): 
>   Enter an RDS DB master password: 
>   Retype password to confirm: 
>   Creating application version archive "app-26c8a-181108_105531".
>   Uploading beebop-staging/app-26c8a-181108_105531.zip to S3. This may take a while.
>   Upload Complete.
>   ERROR: TypeError - Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

Comment: Does the IAM user that you are using have the right Policies?

Comment: Could you please show us the entire stack trace?

Comment: Yes the IAM user belongs to a group with AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess

Comment: Where have you created the credentials file, because you are supposed to have it under ~/.aws/ , but './' isn't the equivalent of '~' . The folder .aws must be under your user home directory.

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant ~/.aws ... appologies

Comment: I think I have found the issue.  It appears that the region wasn't written to the config file in the .elasticbeanstalk directory in my app.  Removing region from the ~/.aws/config and selecting via the prompt seems to have fixed the issue.  Upon confirming this I'll add the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm, the issue was in **[app_directory]/.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml** where the region was not being set.  I removed the region from **~/.aws/config** forcing `eb init` to prompt me to choose the region.  After doing this the region was set correctly and `eb create ...` worked as expected